# Can continuous series be converted to discrete series

Tags: self-study, continuous-data, discrete-data

Is there any method to change the given continuous series to discrete series.There is a problem I have tried every method possible but I could not solve.The problem is in the image please check out that.Can any one give the idea to solve regarding the problem.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRH5v.jpg[image]

Comment: The question cannot be answered without additional assumptions. What assumptions are you making in your class, uniform distributions of ages within each age bin?

Comment: The question is our academic question.It's a direct question .No assumptions are required

Comment: You could have 37 1-year-olds or 37 14-year-olds, and your dataset, as presented, would look exactly the same, so you’re going to have to make some assumptions.

Comment: Teenager age must be assumed as  (13-19) and senior citizen age must be assumed 60 and above

Comment: For seniors, you can just add 11 and 4.  But you can't figure out the number of teens unless you assume something about the 1 to 14 year olds and 15-29 year olds.

Number of teens could be anywhere from 0 to 118.

So, either a) It's a really bad question or b) The question is asking you to make assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment:  Following @Dave's often-used assumption that ages are
distributed uniformly within each interval, the number of
'teenagers' (13-10) might be estimated as 
$$\frac{2}{14}(37) + \frac{5}{15}(81) \approx 36.$$
The number of 'senior citizens' (65 and over) might be
$$\frac{9}{15}(11) + 4 \approx 11.$$

[image]

A more sophisticated approach might be to try to fit the density
function of some appropriate continuous distribution (normal doesn't seem right) to a histogram of
the data and then to use that density function to estimate
numbers in various age groups.